# Improper use of typedef

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using C++ compiler Embarcadero under Windows OS.

This code must be without error, but I am receiving this error message:

**Improper use of typedef 'pt'**

```
typedef struct{
    AnsiString x, y;
}pt;

pt zero(void){
    return (pt){
        INFINITY, INFINITY
    };
}
```

I search online and I read in Embarcadero website:

> Your source file used a typedef symbol where a variable should appear in an expression.
> Check for the declaration of the symbol and possible misspellings.

yet in my idea, it's correct, although I was guessing maybe pt is somehow reserved, I change the variable name to bbkpt, still the same error.

The code above is defined globally.

Any idea how to fix it if it is not right?

Comment: Why typedef at all? Just do `struct pt { ... };`

Comment: I changed the code to your suggestion, I remove typedef at all, still the same result, The error is the same.

Comment: `return pt{...};` Drop the parentheses

Comment: I tried without parentheses before. Still the same. (with and without)

Comment: If you get the same error even though you are not using typedef I suspect that the error is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: It is not a very special code
The whole file is:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

struct pt{
 AnsiString x, y;
};

pt zero(void){
 return pt{
  INFINITY, INFINITY
 };
}

int is_zero(pt p){
 return p.x > 1e20 || p.x < -1e20;
}

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
 : TForm(Owner)
{
}
```

Comment: Put the file in the question. It's hard to read it in comments. Anyway, I just tried it out myself and it compiles just fine. It could possibly be something in `Unit1.h` that messes up the parsing.

Comment: The code you've shown [compiles as written](https://godbolt.org/z/TfeTn5). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code not shown. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: OK guys, thank you, I will have a rest and try it again and if I get anything new I will be back. I appreciate you all.

Comment: Unrelated: You could make just `pt zero() { return {INFINITY, INFINITY}; }`. You don't need a compound literal. It won't solve whatever the problem is though.

Comment: Btw, you not using the classic compiler, are you?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It doesn't compile as written. You had to add definitions for `AnsiString` and `INFINITY`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Even with those it will not compile for OP—that is the complaint.  You mean the problem will not reproduce as written.

Answer (score 3):

Compound literals are a C feature not in standard C++ yet. The C++ compiler you are using does not support them, at least not with the settings you are using.

Comment: Embarcaderos clang enhanced compiler compiles the code just fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: With settings for standard C++, disabling extensions? In the version OP is using?

Comment: I couldn't find any extension that I could turn off to affect that. I currently have tested it in 10.3.3 only. I can try it in 10.2.1 tomorrow if this isn't sorted out by then (I have it on an old computer that I need to connect to be able to do that).

Comment: I tried as I could, now I believe this is the best answer, but, anyway, if someone can suggest a setting change in Embarcadero C++Builder, please let me know. Thanks.